# Discord.js --- TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm Coding A Discord Bot In Javascript, For One of The Commands (!server, displays server name and total members), An error Keeps Popping up. my current Code Is ;

```
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

```
client.on('message', message =>{;
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith("!")){
        const prefix = ("!")
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        if(command == 'help'){
            client.commands.get('!help').execute(message, args);
        } 
        if(command == 'server'){
            client.commands.get('!server').execute(message, args);
        } 
        if(command == 'blacklist'){
            client.commands.get('!blacklist').execute(message, args);
        } 
        if(command == 'safe'){
            client.commands.get('!safe').execute(message, args);
        }
    };
```

The Error Message is

```
            client.commands.get('!server').execute(message, args);
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
```

```
// !server.js File
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
    name: '!server',
    description: "!server",
    execute(message, args){
        message.react('')
        const serverEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        serverEmbed.setTitle(`Server Stats`)
        serverEmbed.addField("Server Name", message.guild.name);
        serverEmbed.addField("Total Members", message.guild.memberCount);
        serverEmbed.addField("Online Members", message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status !== "offline").size);
        serverEmbed.addField("Offline Members", message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "offline").size);
        message.channel.send(serverEmbed);
    }
}
```

The Code Works For The Other 3 Commands Just Not !server. Any Help?

Comment: well obviously the '!server' command does not exist. Please include your command loading code. Otherwise I can't help you. Also make sure that your command/file name is correct

Comment: can you please include the code you use to load your commands? The part with `readdirSync` in it.

Comment: it looks like, for some reason, your command is not loaded correctly. Try to rename it, maybe without the `!` to see if that changes anything.

Comment: I don't exactly know why, but that works, cheers @WorthyAlpaca

Comment: you might want to think about using a, somewhat, more dynamic command handler. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608116/i-am-getting-an-error-typerror-cannot-read-property-execute-of-undefined/64610249#64610249). Only the last part is really relevant for you.